# Post form data to php without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I am trying to post form data, an array to php file without page refresh. I am using ajax which doesn't seem to be working. Below is form syntax and ajax. Can somebody please help me? Thanks.

```
<form name="postcontent" id="postcontent">
function[]; //just for an example of data
<button type="button" id="submitform" onclick="posttophp" >Send</button>

<script>
function posttophp() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp1.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("submitform").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "options.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("
function_Options1[]=function[]")
}
</script>
```

In php, I store function_Options1[] in another variable and use further.

Comment: Use your browsers debugger to see if the ajax is being sent and the response received. You may find it helpful to read this. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/

Comment: did you close off the form with `</form>`? Look at your developer console. There's also no php here.

Comment: `onclick="posttophp"` that doesn't do anything; you need to add the brackets for it in order to call the `posttophp()` "function".

Comment: @SloanThrasher What does [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/1415) have to do with this question? There's no indication of them using a database.

Comment: Yes, I have closed the form. It was a good catch about adding brackets. I added those as well, but still not working. Php file is simple and as below. <?php $function=$post_['function_Options1']; and I ask it to write to the file which is pretty standard format before closing php

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas to try:

1. Maybe the script should be placed before calling the function, but not sure about this.
2. Try `onclick="posttophp();"`